# Setting a bit in an uint64_t in c

Tags: c

Hello I would like to set a bit ( value ) at a pos ( from left to right ). Here is my code that doesn't work for uint64_t ( here it should return 0 and not 1 ) but when I change values to make it works ( with the same logic ) with uint8_t it works. Any ideas? Please.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
int main()
{
    uint64_t x = (uint64_t)1;
    int pos =  63;
    bool value = 0;
    uint8_t z = x;
    z = z >> (64-pos);
    z = z << (64-pos);
    uint64_t a = (uint64_t)1;
    uint64_t d = (uint64_t)0;
    uint64_t y;
    uint64_t c = d;
    uint64_t b = x;
    b = b << (pos+1);
    b = b >> (pos+1);
    if (value == 1)
    {
        y = a;
        y = y << (63-pos);
    }
    else
    {
        y=d;
    }
    c = c|z|y|b;
    printf("%lld",c);
    return c;
}
```

EDIT : I think there is a misunderstood ( I haven't be clear enough, my bad ), actually I have x that is an uint64_t and I have a int pos that is the position of one bit in x, and I have value that is a boolean ( 1 or 0 ) and if value is 1 the bit at the pos in x must become/stay 1 and if value is 0 the bit at the pos in x must become/stay 0.

Comment: `b = b << (pos+1)` invokes undefined behaviour. The right argument is too large.

Comment: Simplify your question; your edit is fairly clear, but the code presented does not relate to that and is doing much more besides.  Rather than adding clarification, delete of edit the content that was not clear in the first place.

Comment: Avoid comparing `bool` with an integer, or indeed anything.  Instead just `if( value )` or `if( !value )`.  That said `value` is a particularly poor name for a Boolean.  In this case `set_bit` would make more sense - `if( set_bit )` is self-documenting.

Comment: Rather then casting literal constants such as `(uint64_t)1` use type suffixes such as `1ull`.   Also you have the wrong format specifier for `c`  : `printf("%ulld",c);`

Answer (score 3):

To set the bit `pos` in `value`, you use

```
value |= ((uint64_t)1) << pos;
```

What is the rest of your code supposed to do?

For the updated question, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54855146/10095817).

Comment: `value` is  `bool` not a `uint64_t`

Comment: Here `value` is the `uint64_t` where the bis is set.

Comment: Yes in your code, but in the question `value` is a boolean that indicates whether the bit should be set or cleared.  To be fair, the question has been edited since you answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
//sets the bit pos to the value. if value is == 0 it zeroes the bit if value !=0 it sets the bit

void setbit(uint64_t *val, int bit, int value)
{
    if(value)
    {
        *val |= ((uint64_t)1 << bit);
    }
    else
    {
        *val &= ~((uint64_t)1 << bit);
    }
}

//sets nbits at location pos to the value of the first nbits of the value parameter.pos + nbits < 63
void setbits(uint64_t *val, int pos, int nbits, uint64_t value)
{
    uint64_t mask = ((uint64_t)((uint64_t)1 << nbits) - 1);

    *val &= ~(mask << pos);
    *val |= (val & mask) << pos;
}
```

And usage with bool

```
#include <stdbool.h>

uint64_t obj;
/* ... */
setbit(&obj, 5, true);  //sets the 5th bit to 1
setbit(&obj, 7, false);  //sets the 7th bit to 0
```

Comment: Note; the need for the  first cast in `(uint64_t)((uint64_t)1 << nbits)` is unclear. 
 It appears necessary.